# Openpyxl - WinError 32 while trying to save workbook after formatting applied

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, formatting, openpyxl

I am unable to save workbooks when I apply formatting to a worksheet (for example, setting row_dimensions to an integer, or column dimensions to an integer).

Code snippet:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws['A1'].value = 'test'
ws.row_dimensions[1] = 10
wb.save('example.xlsx')
```

Traceback info:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<>", line 7, in <module>
    wb.save('practicewb')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 409, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 294, in save_workbook
    writer.save()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 276, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 76, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 216, in _write_worksheets
    self.write_worksheet(ws)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 201, in write_worksheet
    writer.write()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 356, in write
    self.write_rows()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 124, in write_rows
    self.write_row(xf, row, row_idx)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 133, in write_row
    attrs.update(dims.get(row_idx, {}))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 33, in _openpyxl_shutdown
    os.remove(path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\philt\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\openpyxl.gtzivgcp'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I do not have any folders or programs open that are using the workbook, aside from openpyxl itself.

What could be the problem here?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to set the height for the relevant row. Your code just sets the row to be the number 10.

Answer (score 3):

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws['A1'].value = 'test'
ws.row_dimensions[1].height = 10
wb.save('example.xlsx')
```

Comment: @philip tecklenburg Does this help to solve your issue?

Comment: I had the same problem and this solved it for me. This should be the accepted answer